# Facebook API - Never-expire personal token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an app that will auto-push a couple of things to my wall only. Is there any way of getting a never-expiring token for myself, as nobody else will be using my application, it should be somewhat straight forward? I don't see the need for access token expiry when it's only me using the application.

Answer (score 2):

There is no User Token that is valid forever, you can only extend it to 60 days. Btw, autoposting is not allowed anyway, you must read the platform policy before creating any App: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

It does not matter if only you are using the App, the rules apply to everyone.

Comment: So, what if I ever wanted to display my last Facebook status on my website? Or get my current bio? Is there no way around an expiring token?

Comment: you said you want to post stuff on your wall, not on your website. that´s a different story, but not possible either without refreshing the token once in a while. there is no way around it. user profiles are not meant to be used for that anyway, they are kind of "personal". if you want to pust stuff from facebook on your website, use a page. there is a never expiring page token.